# Control order of hashref with YAML::XS

Tags: perl, yaml, libyaml

I'm dumping a data structure to YAML with the `YAML::XS` library:

```
foo => {
    bar => [
        {...},
        {...},
    ],
    baz => [
        {...},
        {...},
    ], 
    ...
}
```

It seems like YAML::XS's default behavior is to sort the keys before dumping them, but this is not what I want.  Humans will have to read and edit the output of this script, so readability is a concern.  Is there a way to control the order that the keys are dumped out so that `foo->{baz}` would come before `foo->{bar}`?

Comment: The docs are [here](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML::XS)

Comment: You can do this using YAML.pm's [`Bless`](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML#Bless-perl-node-yaml-node-class-name) but not sure if it's doable with YAML::XS.

Comment: @ikegami I read that already, it didn't answer my question

Comment: @Floegipoky, It really does.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I ended up swapping out `YAML::XS` for `YAML`,  Thank you very much for pointing out the `Bless` feature.  It's more powerful than I would have liked to use for this but it got the job done.  For future viewers, be aware that unless you know at write-time exactly which keys you're expecting, you'll have to inspect each node that you're `Bless`ing.  Also note that if a key is absent it will generate a dummy entry anyway, so make sure that you check for existence first: `my $blessarray = []; push $blessarray, 'optionalkey' if $table->{optionalkey}; `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML::XS), there is no option that configures the order of hashes. This is further confirmed by looking at `dump_node` and `dump_hash` in `LibYAML/perl_libyaml.c`.